# How can I use NSCalendar range function within Calendar?

Tags: swift, nscalendar

I have the following code which used compile in Swift 2 however won't in Swift 4.2.  The range function that returns a boolean is no longer a part of the Calendar data type however it is a part of the NSCalendar data type.  Is there a way I can use or format this function to make it compile in Swift 4.2?

```
extension Calendar {
    /**
     Returns a tuple containing the start and end dates for the week that the
     specified date falls in.
     */
    func weekDatesForDate(date: NSDate) -> (start: NSDate, end: NSDate) {
        var interval: TimeInterval = 0
        var start: NSDate?
        range(of: .weekOfYear, start: &start, interval: &interval, for: date as Date)
        let end = start!.addingTimeInterval(interval)

        return (start!, end)
    }
}
```

I've tried the following however the range function isn't the same and doesn't compile:

```
extension NSCalendar {
    /**
     Returns a tuple containing the start and end dates for the week that the
     specified date falls in.
     */
    func weekDatesForDate(date: NSDate) -> (start: NSDate, end: NSDate) {
        var interval: TimeInterval = 0
        var start: NSDate?
        range(of: .weekOfYear, start: &start, interval: &interval, for: date as Date)
        let end = start!.addingTimeInterval(interval)

        return (start!, end)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `range(of:start:interval:for:)` in `Calendar` is `dateInterval(of:start:interval:for:)`

Don't use `NSDate` in Swift

```
extension Calendar {
    /**
     Returns a tuple containing the start and end dates for the week that the
     specified date falls in.
     */
    func weekDatesForDate(date: Date) -> (start: Date, end: Date) {
        var interval: TimeInterval = 0
        var start = Date()
        dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &start, interval: &interval, for: date)
        let end = start.addingTimeInterval(interval)

        return (start, end)
    }
}
```

I recommend to use dedicated `DateInterval` as return value rather than a tuple:

```
extension Calendar {
    /**
     Returns a tuple containing the start and end dates for the week that the
     specified date falls in.
     */
    func weekDatesForDate(date: Date) -> DateInterval {
        var interval: TimeInterval = 0
        var start = Date()
        dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &start, interval: &interval, for: date)
        let end = start.addingTimeInterval(interval)
        return DateInterval(start: start, end: end)
    }
}
```

Comment: It says the dateInterval function is unused.  Are you stating that by casting the result to a DateInterval data type basically took care of the problem without needed the dateInterval function?

Comment: Both versions are supposed to work in the same way. Does it say that *the dateInterval function is unused* or ***the result** of the dateInterval function is unused*. The function itself is clearly not unused.

Comment: If you get a warning about *the result is unused* write `_ = dateInterval(...`